# Firebase functions with Julia

Tags: javascript, firebase, websocket, julia

I have developed a front-end for a simulation tool that I have written in Julia. I have decided to use Google Firebase to host the website, but I find it difficult to integrate the Julia code inside of it. On my own PC I created a WebSocket between the Julia and the JS front-end, but this approach does not work with Firebase in its the current implementation.

Does anyone here know a good approach to integrating different languages on Firebase? I thought about using Firebase Functions, but it seems like calling Julia from there is not possible? Right now I am thinking of moving away from Firebase and simply creating a server from scratch to solve the problem. Any advice would be very welcome.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear from your question which part of Firebase you use, but most Firebase services has a [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) which should be callable from pretty much any platform.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated I will try that.

Just to be sure this means that will use my own computer to run Julia and then use firebase as the backend to communicate between the front-end and Julia?

Comment: Cloud Functions for Firebase has no built0in option to execute Julia code. So unless you have another server where you can run that, you'll indeed have to run it on your own machine.

Comment: I have compiled my Julia code into a executable now. Can I use that on Firebase?